# Vercel deploy does not copy and rename my files from npm task

Tags: vercel

I have a static Gatsby website in Vercel and I have an issue with the build method. I have these scripts in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "files": "mv public/sitemap-index.xml public/sitemap.xml && cp ads.txt public/ads.txt",
    "build": "gatsby clean && gatsby build && npm run files",
}
```

but my "files" task does nothing in the Vercel environment for some reason, nothing is renamed and nothing is copied in the output folder in Vercel. Do you know why? I tried different approaches and nothing worked. Am I missing something? I don't have any errors in Vercel logs, nothing at all.

**UPDATE:**

After debugging to see what is going on with the file system in Vercel I can see that actually the "npm run files" command is doing exactly what is told to do. When we list everything in "public" folder we can see that the files are renamed and moved to that folder.

The interesting part is that it is not present in the output folder of Vercel in the end. So probably some cache? Or did something happen between the Vercel build and copy/rename files?